# Change window move funcitonality to mirror OSX's Zooom2

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-management, macosx

On OSX I use Zooom2 to move my windows around with keyboard shortcuts and mouse motion. This operates in a very similar manner to Ubuntu, with the following difference:

- On Zooom2, I have it set so holding down Shift + Cmd when the cursor is over a window and dragging the mouse moves said window. Shift + Alt + mouse move resizes.
- On Ubuntu, window movement is achieved by holding Alt and **clicking** in a window, then dragging the mouse.

The clicking required in Ubuntu is fine when using a mouse, but I find it ends up being a bit of strain when using the trackpad - I miss OSX's no-click version.

Is there a way of customising the window moves so I don't have to actually click?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to adapt the natural-scrolling from when OS X Lion introduced natural/reverse scrolling where by “content tracks finger movement”.

This

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling
```

to your Software Sources

`sudo apt-get update`

then install the ‘naturalscrolling’ package from the Ubuntu Software Centre